# move a database to a different drive on the same server?

Tags: database, sharepoint-foundation

I'm trying to figure out how to point the database of my existing Sharepoint foundation install to the `D:` on my server. It was installed on the `C:` We just upgraded the `D:` to hold a lot more and need that space to be used. Is this

Comment: As @Tim mentions, this is more of a SQL Server question. You could try also asking/searching on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't as much of a SharePoint thing as it is a SQL Server thing. SharePoint is only pointing to a server that has it's database. It has no knowledge, and probably doesn't care which drive the database lives on. You would need to move the database from SQL Server Management Studio. See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/5c0e5ba5-1e1a-4c38-ac92-3e5c50ac6c7b/)

Comment: If you notice a question is off topic, please vote to close it. You can always add a comment as well.

Comment: The only reason I did not vote to close it was because not everyone may be familiar with the way SharePoint is interacting with the database, especially since SharePoint is very 'hands-off' when it comes to SQL Server.

Comment: @Tim Gabrhel, I was wondering if you knew what database the documents were held? I have downloaded what you suggested and see a bunch of databases. Also, does the documents get stored in the database or just a string location?

Comment: You're looking for something called 'WSS_Content', or similar. Using [this](http://blog.rafelo.com/2008/08/move-site-collection-to-new-content.html) link, you can determine which content database your **site collection** resides in. The physical files live somewhere similar to the following: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA. There is an MDF (database) and an LDF (log) for each database.

Comment: I didn't see this answer before asking the next question... chill. go away.

Comment: Sorry for the over reaction. What I saw what you asked a question, I answered, and (as perceived by me), didn't like it, so asked it again hoping for a different answer.

Comment: No, you answered my question completely and I liked it, thank you.