# Which database holds documents?

Tags: document, content-database

I am wondering which database holds documents? I know that the documents are held as BLOBS in the database itself, but I can't seem to figure out what database that is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [move a database to a different drive on the same server?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18283/move-a-database-to-a-different-drive-on-the-same-server)

Comment: What is wrong with the solutions I've previously provided to you? I give you an answer and you create another thread.

Comment: @Tim, what other solutions have you provided?  I only see three other questions from Phil and none of them touch on this.  Also, your possible duplicate seems like a different question to me.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the close votes on this question. The "possible duplicate" is completely different. Yes, the OP asked this in a comment on [the answer by @TimGabrhel](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18283/move-a-database-to-a-different-drive-on-the-same-server/18284#18284) however they have every right to ask this as a new question, and it is more valuable to the community that they have done so.

Comment: Thank you Alex and Abe, Tim probably didn't read the whole thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would take a look at these two links:

- http://ktskumar.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/sharepoint-databases/
- http://grounding.co.za/blogs/neil/archive/2008/08/16/sql-databases-used-in-sharepoint.aspx

They go over the various databases that SharePoint has under the hood and what their purposes are.

**That being said...** I would recommend staying away from directly interacting with SharePoint databases.  Microsoft provides an object model that allows you to perform any actions that you should be performing.  If you manually start mucking around in the database there is a good chance you will blow up your data or render your instance of SharePoint "unsupported"...  Be careful!

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861829%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

> Direct modification of the SharePoint database or its data is not
>   recommended because it puts the environment in an unsupported state.

Comment: +1 Don't do anything to alter the data model or directly insert/update/delete data...and while querying the database is permissible it is ill-advised.

Answer (score 1):

In the content database that the site uses.

Here is a pretty good article: http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2008/08/exactly-where-sharepoint-documents-are.html