# Which Database table stores the XML column mappings for Lists?

Tags: 2013, column, content-database

**First off, I'd like to say that I understand the limitations and the risk of accessing a Sharepoint Database directly. I am not updating the SP Content, just simply querying the data in a SQL View for another application.**

Generally, when I need to create a view for SP data I have had to manually map the List/Library fields to their dynamic database columns. However, this can get fairly tedious depending on the size of the list. For example:

- nvarchar1 = 'First Name'
- nvarchar2 = 'Last Name'
- nvarchar3 = 'Phone Number'

As Sharepoints content is stored dynamically, I figure that there has to be a table which stores these mappings.

Where are the above mappings stored in the content database, and how can I query it so I can dynamically pull data from the AllUserData table for a specific list?

Comment: I would try using SQL Profiler and see what statements gets executed on adding a new field from Browser.

Comment: Even still, I would not recommend it, there are a slew of other tools to get the data out than direct query access.

Comment: Possibe duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18314/which-database-holds-documents ?

Comment: @Eric Alexander - How would you recommend I query this data in SSRS? I can easily hook up a Sharepoint List Datasource, but since I deal with 100's of different templated lists, I need that List Datasource to be dynamic based on the Site Name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give it a try using below sql query.

```
DECLARE @listId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'LISTGUID';
SELECT DISTINCT
     tp_Fields AS 'Fields'                                         
FROM   AllLists
WHERE  tp_ID = @listId
```

If you are using C# code to get the details you can use the following methods.

```
public static string GetFieldXmlString(string connectionString, Guid listId)
{
    string fieldXml = string.Empty;     
    var cmd = [Select command mentioned above]
    var data = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn))
        {
            da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
            da.Fill(data);
        }
    }
    fieldXml = getXml((byte[])data.Rows[0]["Fields"]);
    return fieldXml;
}

private static string getXml(byte[] tpFields)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(tpFields))
    {
        // ignore the first 14 bytes; I'm not sure why but it works!
        for (var index = 0; index <= 13; index++)
            memoryStream.ReadByte();

        var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

        using (var destination = new MemoryStream())
        {
            deflateStream.CopyTo(destination);

            var streamReader = new StreamReader(destination);
            destination.Position = 0;
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps to resolve your query.!!